# Merge multiple videos and one audio with ffmpeg. Loop all the videos while audio is not over

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge

I'm trying to merge an audio file with multiple videos.

**The final output video should contain the full audio and it's not necessary to contain all the videos**

It may contain some secondes from each video.

I tried this solution:
ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y out.mp4

And it worked but just with one video, And what i need is looping multiple videos while audio is not over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `input.txt`:

```
file 'video0.mp4'
file 'video1.mp4'
file 'video2.mp4'
```

Encode:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

- All files listed in `input.txt` must have all the same attributes to concatenate properly.
- See the [FFmpeg concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: It's working... But the size is too large, it's just a 640,388 resolution video.
How can i reduce the size in the same command ?
You can reply here also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712598/reduce-size-of-a-video-made-with-ffmpeg-in-the-same-command