# Reduce size of a video made with ffmpeg in the same command

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

It creates a video from multiple videos and it's working, But the output video size is too big, And my question is how to get a video with a smaller size but without the need of another command.

Comment: When you say: "smaller size", you mean smaller file size? Or smaller geometry (width and height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## H.264

Use `-crf` and `-preset` when encoding with libx264:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 29 -preset slower -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `-crf` Use the highest value that provides an acceptable quality. Default is 23. A value of 29 should be about 50% smaller, but lower quality.
- `-preset` Use the slowest preset you can. Default is `medium`.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

## HEVC/H.265

Should be smaller file size than H.264, but is slower to encode and may not be supported by your player or device:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx265 -crf 34 -preset slow -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- libx265 also uses `-crf` and `-preset`, but the `-crf` values are somewhat different. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

## Forced output file size

File size cannot be pre-determined using `-crf`. If you need to limit the video to be under a certain size use [two-passes](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass). However, this is not "better" than `-crf`, and is slower, more complicated, and is only to be used if you need the output to be a specific size.

## Smaller width x height (resolution)

Add the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale). Example to make width x height 50% smaller:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -vf "scale=iw/2:ih/2" -c:v libx264 -crf 29 -preset slower -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```